# DBMS output not printing

Tags: oracle, plsql, datagrip, dbms-output

Hi I want to write a ISBN validation in PLSql. But dbms_output.put_line doesnt output anything. I dont have any errors but dbms_output is yellow marked with the warning:

> Unable to resolve symbol 'dbms_output'
>
> Inspection info: This inspection performs unresolved SQL references check.

. Im working in DataGrip and yes I have enabled SYS.dbms_output.

```
DECLARE
  v_isbn VARCHAR(13) := 9783161484100;
BEGIN
  isbn_validation(v_isbn);
end;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE isbn_validation
(
    p_isbn VARCHAR
)
IS
  v_isbn VARCHAR(13);
  v_checksum INTEGER := 0;
BEGIN
    if LENGTH(p_isbn) = 10 THEN
        v_isbn := CONCAT('978',p_isbn);
        v_checksum := isbn13_checksum(v_isbn);
        if(v_checksum = -1)THEN dbms_output.put_line(v_isbn || ' is a invalid isbn');
        else
          v_isbn:=CONCAT(v_isbn,CAST(v_checksum AS CHAR));
          isbn_validation(v_isbn);
          dbms_output.put_line(v_isbn || ' is a valid isbn');
        end if;
    elsif LENGTH(v_isbn) = 13 THEN
      v_checksum := isbn13_checksum(v_isbn);
        if(v_checksum = -1)THEN dbms_output.put_line(v_isbn || ' is a invalid isbn');
        else
          v_isbn:=CONCAT(v_isbn,CAST(v_checksum AS CHAR));
          isbn_validation(v_isbn);
          dbms_output.put_line(v_isbn || ' is a valid isbn');
        end if;
    end if;
end;



CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION isbn13_checksum
(
    v_isbn VARCHAR
)
RETURN INTEGER
IS
  v_checksum INTEGER := 0;
  v_remainder INTEGER := 0;
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1..12 LOOP
        if MOD(i,2) = 1 THEN
          if SUBSTR(v_isbn,i) = 'X' THEN
            v_checksum := v_checksum + 10;
          else v_checksum := v_checksum + CAST(SUBSTR(v_isbn,i) AS INTEGER);
          end if;
        else
          if SUBSTR(v_isbn,i) = 'X' THEN
            v_checksum := v_checksum + (10 * 3);
          else v_checksum := v_checksum + (CAST(SUBSTR(v_isbn,i) AS INTEGER) * 3);
          end if;
        end if;
    end loop;
    v_remainder := mod(v_checksum, 10);
    if v_remainder = 0 THEN RETURN -1;
    elsif(10-v_remainder)=10 THEN RETURN 0;
    else RETURN (10 - v_remainder);
    end if;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try explicitly enabling DBMS_OUTPUT using dbms_output.enable

```
DECLARE
  v_isbn VARCHAR(13) := 9783161484100;
BEGIN
dbms_output.enable;
  isbn_validation(v_isbn);
end;
```

Comment: That won't enable it in the client.

Answer (score 1):

Execute `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON` and run your code again.

Answer (score 0):

Might be this bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-4702
Please, use the latest version.